# Docusign REST API Getting recipient URL for document envelope

Tags: php, json, curl, docusignapi

I have a web app that takes a user through a series of forms and then generates a pdf with their answers. I want to add a Docusign signature to the end of the pdf form, so that after finishing the online form they are asked to sign it in an iframe.

I started with this doc - https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/signing-from-your-app and then took step 2 from this doc to create my envelope with a document - https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email

My code created the Envelope ID fine, but when I try to get the URL using `/envelopes/$envelopeId/views/recipient` I get the status 400 error:

```
{ "errorCode": "ACCOUNT_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_ENVELOPE", "message": "This account is not authorized to access the requested envelope." }
```

Here is my full code below:

```
<?php

$docusign_username = "my@username.com";
$docusign_password = "mypassword";
$docusign_integrator_key = "my-integrator-key";

$applicant_email = "johnsmith@emailaddress.com";
$applicant_name = "John Smith";
$applicant_unique_id = "123";

$application_unique_id = "31587";
$application_form_pdf = "31587.pdf";

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $docusign_username . "</Username><Password>" . $docusign_password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $docusign_integrator_key . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (retrieves baseUrl and accountId)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results
echo "accountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create an envelope with document
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data =
    array (
        "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Please sign " . $application_form_pdf,
        "documents" => array(
            array("documentId" => $application_unique_id, "name" => $application_form_pdf)
            ),
        "recipients" => array(
            "signers" => array(
                array(
                    "email" => $applicant_email,
                    "name" => $applicant_name,
                    "clientUserId" => $applicant_unique_id,
                    "recipientId" => $applicant_unique_id,
                    "tabs" => array(
                        "signHereTabs" => array(
                            array(
                                "xPosition" => "100",
                                "yPosition" => "100",
                                "documentId" => $application_unique_id,
                                "pageNumber" => "1"
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    , "status" => "sent"
    // , "status" => "created"
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$file_contents = file_get_contents($application_form_pdf);

// Create a multi-part request. First the form data, then the file content
$requestBody =
     "\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."--myboundary\r\n"
    ."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."$data_string\r\n"
    ."--myboundary\r\n"
    ."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
    ."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"$application_form_pdf\"; documentid=".$application_unique_id." \r\n"
    ."\r\n"
    ."$file_contents\r\n"
    ."--myboundary--\r\n"
    ."\r\n";

// Send to the /envelopes end point, which is relative to the baseUrl received above.
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )
);
$json_response = curl_exec($curl); // Do it!

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "Error calling DocuSign, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text: ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

//--- display results
echo "Envelope created! Envelope ID: " . $envelopeId . "\n";

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 3 - Get the Embedded Signing View
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array(
      "returnUrl" => "https://www.docusign.com/devcenter"
    , "authenticationMethod" => "None"
    , "authenticationInstant" => "None"
    , "userId" => $applicant_unique_id
    , "clientUserId" => $applicant_unique_id
    // , "email" => $applicant_email
    // , "userName" => $applicant_name
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl."/envelopes/$envelopeId/views/recipient" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$url = $response["url"];

//--- display results
echo "Embedded URL is: \n\n" . $url . "\n\nNavigate to this URL to start the embedded signing view of the envelope\n";

?>
```

Any ideas would be gratefully received, thanks!

Comment: you're doing curl uploads all wrong (or, even if you're technically doing it correct, which i doubt,  you're doing it in a very error-prone way), don't set content-length, curl will do it for you, and don't write the normal HTTP POST multipart/form-data upload request body manually, again, let curl do it for you, with CURLFile. also you're sending too many \r\n's because curl will add \r\n\r\n to separate HTTP HEADERS with HTTP BODY per the http specs automatically, so what you're sending now is probably \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n which corrupts the request body

Comment: ohhh, are you doing it because the "documentid" in Content-disposition which can't be set with CURLFile? that'd explain it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When obtaining the recipient view (the signing view), try identifying the signer by just specifying the

```
"email" => $email, # signer's email
"userName" => $recipientName,
"clientUserId" => $clientUserId
```

as shown in the embedded signing recipe.

Don't set the `userId`

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!!